# iPhone Configuration Utility. Can't remove/install any Configuration profile

Tags: iphone, utility

I have following problem, I installed iPhone Configuration Utility tool on my mac, then I tested some Configuration profiles, I installed/removed them - everything was perfect, then I unfortunately delete some certificates from my keychain (I believe they were related to this tool), after this I can't neither remove nor install any Configuration profile. 
I tried to reinstall Utility tool but this did not help.

Please share ideas how to make it works again

Answer (score 0):

You need the Apple WWDR Intermediate Certificate installed on that machine.

Comment: Your edit suggestion on Dmitry's question is pretty extensive and includes a lot of content that isn't in comments here. What's up?